# Hibernate Unable to resolve property of subclass when querying by superclass JpaRepository after Spring Boot 3 Hibernate 6 migration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to migrate from Spring Boot 2.7 to Spring Boot 3.0.

I have entities in a herarchical relationship using Joined inheritance type and a JpaRepository typed to the abstract superclass.  Since the migration, I have failing integration tests like the example below when trying to run the method findByKey() on my JpaRepository:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to resolve property: requestItemConfiguration
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.getPropertyIndex(EntityMetamodel.java:872)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getPropertyIndex(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2781)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.BatchEntitySelectFetchInitializer.endLoading(BatchEntitySelectFetchInitializer.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.finishUp(StandardRowReader.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:443)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.lambda$new$0(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:305)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:546)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.list(QuerySqmImpl.java:1032)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:457)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.getSingleResult(QuerySqmImpl.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:193)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:148)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 87 common frames omitted
```

When debugging the code I can see that Hibernate is trying to set a property of a subclass into the abstract superclass EntityMetamodel and failing. What should be changed for this to  work in Hibernate 6 ?

The entity hierarchy:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "request")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class JpaRequest {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "kee", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String key;
.
.
.
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "abstract_request_item")
public abstract class JpaAbstractRequestItem extends JpaRequest {
.
.
.
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "request_item")
public class JpaRequestItem extends JpaAbstractRequestItem {

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST })
    @JoinColumn(name = "config_id", nullable = true)
    private JpaRequestItemConfiguration requestItemConfiguration;
.
.
.
```

The JpaRepository

```
public interface JpaRequestRepository extends JpaRepository<JpaRequest, Long> {

    JpaRequest findByKey(String key);
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Spring Boot 3.0.1 / Hibernate 6.1.6 seems to have solved the issue.